# jquery autocomplete sends empty $_GET["term"]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

My query is very simple. I cannot get selected values sent from my Jquery autocomplete function in my php page. I will explain further. First, here is the code from my html page.

```
<form action="http://localhost/SearchRes/" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="searchbyvalue" id="a" class="a" placeholder="Type a letter to search"><br><br>
</form>
```

My script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#a").autocomplete({
                    source:'search.php',
                    minLength:1
                });
            });
 </script>
```

Further, my search.php is trying to receive the letters entered in the textbox using $_GET["term"] as follows:

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])
{
  $return_arr = array('Generate Ideas', 'Define Products');
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

However, my problem is that the $_GET["term"] is never set. If I remove the 'if' condition, the code works fine. I have also tried using $_REQUEST["term"], but is it also not working. What am I doing wrong here? Please advise.

I am trying to search a database using the characters entered by the user. So I have to further use the values in $_GET["term"] to form a query and search the database. However since the values are never received in the php file, my work is stalled at this point.

Comment: i think this is okay, autocomplete uses that term. my concern only is that the php path. this works http://codepad.viper-7.com/FagzOE the only difference is that my php path is correct `document.URL` (same page) just make sure your PHP path is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your if condition, you forget to use close the brackets.

```
if(isset($_GET['term'])) 
{
  $return_arr = array('Generate Ideas', 'Define Products');
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Enjoy..............

Answer (score 0):

Please send argument to server by using ajax.

```
 source: function( request, response ) {
               $.ajax({
                   type:"GET",
                   url : 'search.php?term='+$("#a").val(),
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function( data ) {
                            response(data);
                   }
               });
          },
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `if` condition is not properly written:

`if (isset($_GET['term'])` should be `if (isset($_GET['term']))`